# My setOnLongClickListner is not working

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am trying to change the text by long clicking on button but I am getting the error in the second line.How can i resolve this?please help

```
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    public void onlongClick(View v) {
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t.setText("text changed!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Check the case of the `onLongClick()` method..

Comment: It works but can you please explain why this is happening? we can give any name to our methods

Comment: You can't change the name of this method because it's part of the interface View.OnLongClickListener. You need to implement it, so you can't change it's name.

Comment: In this case you are overriding the `onLongClick` method of the `View.OnLongClickListener` interface.  To be more proper, you should also include an `@Override` annotation, though that's not required.  So, in order to implement the interface you need to implement all the methods defined by it.  So, you are actually not choosing an arbitrary name in this case.

Comment: Thank  you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake, **onLongClick**, not onlongClick (capital ***L***)

When overriding the **onLongClick** method of the *View.OnLongClickListener* interface, you cannot change the method name.

The correct syntax:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
b.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t.setText("text changed!");
    }
});
```

To be more proper, you should also include an *@Override* annotation, though that's not required.

Answer (score 0):

For android.widget.Button view this is the syntax for long click interface:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
...
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

b.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ((Button) v).setText("Long pressed");
        return false;
    }
});
```